# Angular 2 unit testing - getting error Failed to load 'ng:///DynamicTestModule/module.ngfactory.js'

Tags: angular, webpack, karma-runner

I have angular 2 webpack application, all webpack,karma configuration created as per angular.io webpack guide. 
I am not using aot.
I am writing jasmine unit test spec to test my components.
First I tried without async block, in that case , unit test just get execute only till fixture.detectChanges() call, code after that doesn't get executed. Seems like fixture.detectChanges call getting blocked infinitely.

I tried by including code in async block.
Then I get following error.
Error:Failed to execute 'send' on 'XMLHttpRequest' : Failed to load 'ng:///DynamicTestModule​/module.ngfactory.js'

---

Code without async

```
beforeeach(()=> {
TestBed.configureTestingModule({
imports:[],
declaration :[Mycomp],
providers:[{ provide:MyService, useclass:MyMockService}]
});
 fixture=TestBed.createComponent(Mycomp);
 console.log(' before detect changes'):
 fixture.detectChanges():
 console.log('after detect changes');// this is not getting   
    logged .. karma shows 0 of 1 executed successfully

 });
```

---

With async

```
  beforeeach(async(()=> {
 TestBed.configureTestingModule({
  imports:[],
  declaration :[Mycomp],
  providers:[{ provide:MyService,       useclass:MyMockService}]
  });
   fixture=TestBed.createComponent(Mycomp);
    fixture.detectChanges():
  }));
```

getting error Failed to load dynamictestmodule/module.ngfactory.js

Answer (score 104, accepted):

I ran into this issue myself yesterday. The problem was that I had an Input() property on my component class that I wasn't setting in the test. So for example, in my-component.ts:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-component'
})
export class MyComponent {
  @Input() title: string;
}
```

and my-component.spec.ts:

```
beforeEach(() => {
  fixture = TestBed.createComponent(MyComponent);
  component = fixture.componentInstance;
  component.title = 'Hello there!' // <-- this is required!
  fixture.detectChanges();
});
```

Or you could provide a default value in the component somewhere. Either way, the test will crash if any inputs are not set and you'll get that unintuitive error.

Note: Running `ng test -sm=false` will give the actual error message causing the problem. Credit: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45802115/61311

Comment: This is true, but I also get the same error sometimes when I have a service that is not properly mocked or if my component is trying to access a null value returned by one of those services.  Still a valid answer, but beware that this might not always fix the issue.

Comment: Just figured out, you can get a better error message by setting the `sourcemap` option to false : `ng test --sourcemap=false`

Comment: @blo0p3r That's a good catch! setting sourcemap to false turns the useless XMLHttpRequest error into the actual root error.

Comment: In my case `--sourcemap=false` removed the error entirely ^^

Comment: Using a custom script in package.json does not work with -sm=false and karma. ie 
"scripts": { 
  "custom-test": "karma start --single-run=false -sm=false" 
}
You must use ng test -sm=false.

Comment: yes, this might be one of the sources, but in my case component didn't have any properties, but I did incorrect mocking.

Comment: when I use `--sm=false` all cases are passed, not getting any error message

Answer (score 77):

To find out what's really causing the error, disable source maps:

For angular-cli >= v6.x:

```
ng test --source-map=false
```

For angular-cli v1.x:

```
ng test -sm=false
```

You will then see a better error, e.g. "Cannot read property 'x' of undefined" **in the actual source file that's causing the error**.  For some reason, there's a bug with sourcemaps right now in testing, and you just get this cryptic error.

Comment: *-sm* or *-sourcemaps* doesn't work on my side (CLI version?), instead *-source-map* works.

Answer (score 18):

running tests with `--sourcemaps=false` will not fail Karma silently but give you some detail about the error instead.

Answer (score 6):

**Adding on to Dan Field's answer**

This is a problem with the `Angular Cli` version **1.2.2 or newer**.  Run your test with `--sourcemaps=false` and you will get the right error messages.

> ng test --sourcemaps=false

shorthand for this is:

> ng test -sm=false

See details here: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/7296

Comment: This should be a comment, or better yet, an edit to the other answer

Comment: Thanks @AndréWerlang for your useful comment. Appreciate it!

Answer (score 5):

I also had this issue and it was due to malformed mocked data. 
In my component I had a service which made a http call.

something like: (**service code**)

```
getData() {
   return this.http.get(obj);
}
```

In the component I called this function and subscribed to it: (**component code**)

```
this.service.getData().subscribe((data) => {
  this.componentData = data.things; //**<=== part that broke everything**
}, (error) => {
  console.log(error);
});
```

**Solution:**

When I mocked out the service function I failed to return data that had the attribute `things`. This is what caused the XMLHttpRequest failure, I guess to angular it looked like the error happened as if it was the HTTP request. Making sure that I returned the correct attributes on any mocked HTTP requests fixed the issues.

Hope this clears things up. Below is the code for the implementation of the mock.

(**component.specs**)

```
function fakeSubscribe(returnValue,errorValue) {
  return {
    subscribe:function(callback,error){
      callback(returnValue);
      error(errorValue);
    }
  }
}



 class MockService {
      getData() {
        var fakeData = {
          things:[]
        }
        return fakeSubscribe(fakeData,0);
      }
   }
```

Comment: Was trying to figure this out, and similar concept. My mock services were returning types other than Observable, when the component was expecting an Observable.

Answer (score 3):

This is the most deceiving error message that I've ever encountered in Angular.

In my case it had nothing to do with *sending*, nothing to do with *XmlHttpRequest* - at least not on the level you'd guess when trying to follow the message.

It was too about mocking a class, namely ngrx/store. I introduced two Observable methods in a container that had not been included in my mock-up class before and I forgot to do so when I started using those. Once added to the mock-up, the error went away.

...leaving Karma happy to be able to *execute 'send' from the XmlHttpRequest* whatever it means.

Comment: @KevinOrfas, I had the same issue and a similar resolution to my problem. In my case, a component nested inside the component I was testing made an HTTP call. I needed to mock the HTTP service to get past their bizarre error.

Comment: @user776686 , How you mocked the class and how you resolved, could you please give some info.

Answer (score 2):

I was bitten by the same error next day - this time the problem was buried in the HTML file. Using a simple array length test for `*ngIf`

```
<ng-container *ngIf="myArray.length > 0">
```

had to be refactored into

```
<ng-container *ngIf="myArrayNotEmpty">
```

with a getter as in:

```
get myArrayNotEmpty(){
  return this.myArray && this.myArray.length > 0;
}
```

I am a bit irritated though that such a variety of causes is covered by one very misleading and unhelpful message.

Comment: You've answered this question twice - and both answers were relevant to me in different sections of my codebase. I am rather irritated by this issue.

Comment: You could also do `<ng-container *ngIf="myArray?.length > 0">` instead. Since your code broke because myArray wasn't available at that time and got added afterwards. Adding *?* is lazy checking and does the same as what you have achieved in your external function.

Comment: @markus You are obviously right, I have learned it as time went by. I even forgot I answered this question ;-)

Answer (score 1):

In my case, my mock service was missing some public variables accessed by the component in the ngOnInit method.

Answer (score 0):

I just had this issue as well. It turned out to be a simple null reference error in my component in one of my *ngIf checks.

I would suggest running ng serve and checking the component is working in the browser without any errors, or simply run *ng test --source-map=false* to get a more useful error message.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error when I accessed a variable of an undefined object.

Example:

**Component:**

```
soemthing = {}
```

**Template:**

```
<demo-something [someinput]="something.anotherthing.data"> ...
```

So `something` was defined, `anotherthing` was undefined and `data` could therefor not be accessed.

Very annoying error and as far as I could tell not in the list yet :)