# Angular 5 Testing returns errors

Tags: angular, testing, webpack, angular-material

I am having some troubles with an Angular Project. I am just learning Angular and encountering all sort of errors along the way.

My project is compiling and running fine but whenever I am trying to run an "ng test" to see if my test succeed I am getting all sort of errors back. They look like this:

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/webdriver-js-extender/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/firefox/extension.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in '
```

or

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/tough-cookie/lib/cookie.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'net' in
```

And so on. I read about the fs that I was supposed to add target: 'node' in the webpack config. When I did an ng Eject the webpack config file had this

```
...
"node": {
    "fs": "empty",
...
```

My test looks something like this, I'm only attaching the part where errors have started:

```
it('should send credentials on submit', () => {
  let fixture = TestBed.createComponent(LoginComponent);
  let component: LoginComponent = fixture.componentInstance;
  let element = fixture.nativeElement;

  fixture.detectChanges();

  element.username = expectedUsername;


  element.query(by.id('login-username')).value = expectedUsername;
  element.query(by.id('login-username')).dispatchEvent(new Event('input'));
  element.query(by.id('login-password')).value = expectedPassword;
  element.query(by.id('login-password')).dispatchEvent(new Event('input'));
```

Comment: Please create a git repo and share the same. Its hard to just comment when you have already tried two possible solution

Comment: Have you tried running ng test with source maps off? That helps me sometimes. ng-test -sm=false I found it on an answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45399079/2391959)

Answer (score 4):

Two potential possibilities that I see:

1. You may be importing a module incorrectly, this is very easy to do with IDEs that auto import for you. See the last comment on this thread for an example: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/8357
2. The `fs` module is not supported in Angular (see the link bellow) since it requires the use of native code not available to the browser. In the code you provided you *are not* using `fs`. Is it possible you have imported it somewhere in your project? If you haven't directly imported it, it is possible that *one of your libraries has*. You may want to review the libraries you have `npm install`'ed for ones that don't support the browser. https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/8272

As the comments on your post suggest, if you add more code (or link to a GitHub repository) we may be able to offer additional suggestions.

Comment: What I could tell is that the fs is coming from protactor from testing ... Apparently it's being used when I am using the by method to select an element. (I'm using material components)

Answer (score 1):

You have to just delete the node modules folder inside project and run command 'npm install'.
and check whether your problem will be solved or not..