# Angular testing component with ActivatedRoute

Tags: angular, jasmine, angular2-routing, karma-jasmine

I have a big problem with testing component that uses ActivatedRoute - I only want to pass the default test "component.toBeTruthy"

Component class:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-room',
  templateUrl: './room.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./room.component.css']
})
export class RoomComponent implements OnInit {

  roomId:string;

  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.roomId = this.route.snapshot.params.id;
  }

}
```

Test:

```
describe('RoomComponent', () => {
  let component: RoomComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<RoomComponent>;

  beforeEach(async(() => {

    let temp = new ActivatedRouteStub();

    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ RoomComponent ],
      imports: [MaterialModule, FormsModule, RouterModule, BrowserModule,BrowserAnimationsModule],
      providers: [MatDialog, MatToolbar, RoomService,
        {
          provide: ActivatedRoute, useValue: {}
        }
      ],
      schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA, NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA]
    })
    .compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(RoomComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

The problem is, that when I start tests it's fails with strange error:

> Chrome 65.0.3325 (Mac OS X 10.13.4) ERROR
>     {
>       "message": "Uncaught NetworkError: Failed to execute 'send' on 'XMLHttpRequest': Failed to load 'ng:///DynamicTestModule/RoomComponent_Host.ngfactory.js'.\nat http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/polyfills.bundle.js:2206:25\n\nError: Failed to execute 'send' on 'XMLHttpRequest': Failed to load 'ng:///DynamicTestModule/RoomComponent_Host.ngfactory.js'.\n    at http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/polyfills.bundle.js:4970:35\n    at XMLHttpRequest.proto.(anonymous function) [as send] (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/polyfills.bundle.js:3386:24)\n    at Array. (node_modules/source-map-support/browser-source-map-support.js:107:134)\n    at node_modules/source-map-support/browser-source-map-support.js:101:106\n

If I remove this line `this.roomId = this.route.snapshot.params.id;` from ngOnInit, everything working.

What's happening?

Comment: Two things: try turning sourcemaps off when running the tests to maybe get more feedback on the failure; and consider using the `RouterTestingModule` for a more controlled test environment.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular tests failing with Failed to execute 'send' on 'XMLHttpRequest'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45399079/angular-tests-failing-with-failed-to-execute-send-on-xmlhttprequest)

Comment: I've just seen your first answer with the router testing module @jonrsharpe, I was completely oblivious to that. You should make an answer with that ! I'm removing my other comments & answers as they are useless or just parroting.

Comment: sourcemaps off helped!
- I have to provide {snapshot:{params:{id:''}}}

Answer (score 2):

My gut says the error message is probably has nothing to do with the actual problem.

The issue is that you are using `{}` as provider for `ActivatedRoute`. Then, in your component, you are trying to access `ActivatedRoute`, which in the test case, is `{}`.

Can you try replacing your `providers` to:

```
providers: [MatDialog, MatToolbar, RoomService,
{
  provide: ActivatedRoute, useValue: {
    snapshot: { params: { id: 123 } }
  }
}];
```

Answer (score 0):

so to update this with the reactive params on the activated route I had to do the following inside of my `TestBed.configurationTestingModule`

```js
 await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
  imports: [HttpClientTestingModule], // add any additional imports needed.
  declarations: [ChecklistComponent], //call up your component here
  providers: [
    {
      provide: ActivatedRoute, // needed
      useValue: {
        params: new BehaviorSubject<{ id: string }>({
          id: faker.datatype.uuid(),
        }),
      }, // I had to wrap the usevalue with a params
    },
  ],
  schemas: [NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA], // optional
});
```

in my component I had the following:

```js
    ngOnInit(): void {
// using a subscribe method for reactivity
  this.router.params.subscribe((params) => {
    this.projectId = params["id"];
  });
    }
```