# Angular - Access to XMLHttpRequest - CORS issue in unit test

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine

I am encountering this CORS issue in my spec file in my angular test. Not sure how to fix this. The issue happens in the second line

```
beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(FhcComponent); //ISSUE HAPPENS HERE
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });
```

Here is the full error I am seeing in console.

*Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'ng:///FhcComponent/%C9%B5fac.js' from origin 'http://localhost:9876' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, chrome-untrusted, https.*

Comment: Have you tried what is proposed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45399079/angular-tests-failing-with-failed-to-execute-send-on-xmlhttprequest)?

Comment: Yes. I have no Input() in my component. I have tried source-maps false, but doing this does not allow me to debug the spec file. There are other tests in this file that I need to fix(like TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'pipe')), which is caused by the issue with the TestBed.createComponent

Comment: Are you mocking everything in your test module, including any child components?

Comment: @WillAlexander no. I have a bunch of ViewChild - TemplateRef, and a ViewChilden .
Should I mock them?

Comment: ViewChildren themselves don't need to be mocked. Does your component display any other components? Does it inject any services? What error is shown when you add the source maps flag?

Comment: It does display another component (I see 'ap-select-autocomplete' child component). I see these in my constructor ->     private router: Router,
    private someService: SomeService,
    private someMoreService: SomeMoreService,
    public dialog: MatDialog

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242687/discussion-between-gani-lastra-and-will-alexander).

Answer (score -1):

The error message might be misleading.

This error can happen if you accesses some attribute in the template that is not initialized.